# How to test asp application in browserstack or other cross-browser tools?

Tags: asp-classic, cross-browser, browserstack

I have created a simple asp page, which is works fine in `IIS` server.

I want test this page in various browsers, so I choose [this][1] online tester, but it does not work.

I tried to refresh the virtual directory and tried again, still I didn't get any results. How can I test my asp page in browserstack or another cross browser tool?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="invite_main"> 
 <%
 if session("NotLoggedIn_OldInvite") = "0" then
 %>
        <tr><td class="tdheader"><!--#include file="xx/include/xx_xxy.asp"  --></td></tr>     
<%
end if
%>
```

Comment: If you are using online tool to test, doesn't your application need to be uploaded on remote server? How can you test it from your localhost?

Comment: but already i tested in browserstack for localhost pages(i created using html and css and jquery).. thanks. My question is, why didn't test the asp page? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by [MrZapzup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987460/mrzapzup) in their comment:

> If you are using online tool to test, doesn't your application need to
>   be uploaded on remote server? How can you test it from your localhost?

And it's fully correct. Your application needs to be accessible from outside (preferrably with a human readable URL) to allow testing it with online tools.